# Find particular items from the list object

Tags: c#, list, object, find

I have a list of objects:

```
 List<Object> allUserDatas = new List<Object>();
```

I have read the data form database and store the record (row) in this `allUserDatas` list.

```
allUserDatas = getUserData(userDetails.Ownerid, userDetails.LoggedIn);
```

When I am trying to get the data from this list, I could not do that.

[image]

How can I get a particular item of data from this list?

For ex : AssignedToGroup and CallerId only

I have used Entity Framework, by using that I have read my data and assign it to `List<object>`

```
public List<object> getUserData(string Id,DateTime loggedIn) 
{ 
    List<object> userDatas = new List<object>(); 

    using (UsersEntities entity = new UsersEntities()) 
    { 
         tblUserData data = new tblUserData(); 
         userDatas.Add(entity.tblUserDetails.Where(x => x.Ownerid == Id && x.LoggedIn==loggedIn).FirstOrDefault()); 
    } 

    return userDatas; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

after seeing your code

```
// And for the love of all thins neat and tidy in this world
// start methods with a capital letter :)
public tblUserData GetUserData(string Id, DateTime loggedIn)
{
   using (UsersEntities entity = new UsersEntities())
   {
      return entity.tblUserDetails
                   .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Ownerid == Id && x.LoggedIn == loggedIn);
   }

}
```

**Original**

Be easier if its typed

```
List<tblUserDetail> allUserDatas = new List<tblUserDetail>();

// populate it some how

allUserDatas = getUserData(userDetails.Ownerid, userDetails.LoggedIn).Cast<tblUserDetail>();

// now you can use Linq, yehaaa
var filter = allUserDatas.Where(x => CallerId == "asdfadsf).ToList();
```

[Enumerable.Cast Method (IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Casts the elements of an IEnumerable to the specified type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use where clause in Linq

```
allUserDatas.Where(C => C.CallerId == "asdfadsf")
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to cast the values in the list:

```
var soughtItem =  allUserDatas.Cast<tblUserDetails>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.CallerId == "asdfadsf");
```

It's pretty straight forward.  The key is that you need to cast the object to the type you really want to use.

This will also work:

```
        var soughtItem = allUserDatas.SingleOrDefault(o => ((tblUserDetails)o).CallerId == "asdfadsf") as Item;
```

These examples will give you an error if more than one matches.  You could use FirstOrDefault, too, like  you did, or if your goal is to select more than one, you can do this:

```
var results = items.Where(o => ((tblUserDetails)o).CallerId == "asdfadsf")
                   .Select(o => o as tblUserDetails).ToList();
```

You have a lot of options.